# Difference between SomeInterface.class and SomeClass.class?

Tags: java

I am looking out for the difference between `SomeInterface.class` and `SomeClass.class` in Java. Can anybody explain this?

Edit: Say `SomeClass` implements `SomeInterface`.

Comment: Um, one's a class literal for an interface (presumably) whereas one is an a class literal for a class (presumably). It's hard to be any more specific with so little context.

Comment: `SomeClass1.class` is also different from `SomeClass2.class`. What do you expect?

Comment: You really should check out java tutorials what can be found by google, better to read and try them before you start working in it. These are very essentials of OOP in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in java are used to hold data and provide operations on that data. 
[Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) are used to implment [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). They define operations implmenting classes musst provide so that they have similar behaviours for thier common parts.
You can think of an interface as a kind of contract.

let's say you have some vehicles and want for each vehicle to know how many wheels it has.
A car, a motorcycle and some othe vehicle where you dont know exactly how many wheels it has and have to count them first.
So you can use an Interface to force each vehicle to provide the number of wheels it has.

```
interface Vehicle {
    // define the contract
    int getNumberOfWheels();
}

class Car implements Vehicle {
    // respect the contract by prividing an implmentation for the method getNumberOfWheels()
    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return 4;
    }
}

class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {
    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return 2;
    }
}

class GenericVehicle implements Vehicle {
    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return countWheels();
    }

    private int countWheels() {
        int c=0;
        // count...
        return c;
    }
}


// using the classes / diferent types of vehicles
Vehicle v1 = new Car();
Vehicle v2 = new Motorcycle();
Vehicle v3 = new GenericVehicle();

System.out.println("Vehicle 1 has " + v1.getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels.");
System.out.println("Vehicle 2 has " + v2.getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels.");
System.out.println("Vehicle 3 has " + v3.getNumberOfWheels() + " wheels.");
```

For each new typ of vehicles you want to add you will have to implment the Interface `Vehicle` if you want to habe it behave like the other ones.

This is not everithing about Interfaces but i hope this will help you a little in undestanding them.